# Preenchimento com TemplateField Dinâmico

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Eu crio dinamicamente o `templatefield` para a minha `gridview`, quando chego a gridview é renderizada, obtenho o erro que o elemento "C" não existe como nomes das colunas.

O código que ocorre o erro é:

```
 dataValue = DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, _columnName);
```

O problema é que o `ColumnName` tem o seguinte nome `C.json` e o `DataBinder.Eval` só lê até ao ponto. Isso explica o erro e ler apenas até o "C".

Como posso fazer para que leia todo o nome, incluindo o ponto?

Comment: Você poderia colocar a exceção que está recebendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando a forma comum do `DataBinder.Eval` realmente não funciona para nomes de campos que contenham `.`.

As formas alternativas são:

```
((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["C.json"]
```

ou

```
DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "C.json")
```

*Eu, particularmente, acho a segunda forma mais elegante e simples.*

Isso acontecer porque `DataBinder.Eval` espera, no segundo parâmetro, uma `expression` para encontrar o nome da coluna ou propriedade de uma classe. Dessa forma, o ponto influência na resolução do parâmetro.

Veja mais detalhes sobre o método `DataBinder.Eval` no [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx).

**Um exemplo**

O HTML:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ProductList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        O id é: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %> <br /> 
        Para o item: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "item") %> <br />
        Valor com ponto: <%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["C.json"] %> <br />
        Outra forma: <%# DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "C.json") %> <br />

        <br />
        <hr />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

C# no `page_load` para preencher o repeater:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var products = new DataTable();
    DataRow row;

    products.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "id" });
    products.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "item" });
    products.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "C.json"});

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        row = products.NewRow();
        row["id"] = i;
        row["item"] = "item " + i.ToString();
        row["C.json"] = "valor com . no nome";
        products.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    ProductList.DataSource = products;
    ProductList.DataBind();

}
```

O resultado:

[image: Resultado de um dos itens do repeater]